# Is there documentation regarding specific time frames when using Bixby DateTimeExpressions from viv.time library?

Tags: javascript, datetime, bixby, bixbystudio

For instance, when training the utterance "this afternoon" is there clear documentation regarding how the library understands it?

Comment: I would recommend running this in the simulator and checking the result.

Comment: Thank you for you answer @dogethis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, for bringing this issue to our attention. We are reviewing our options to provide this information and will update our documentation to reflect it.

Comment: Thank you very much. @BixbyDevSupportOne